# What is Bouncy Castle's BrokenJCEBlockCipher class used for?

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, jce

I've been investigating Bouncy Castle's API for a while and I just encountered some classes in the JCE provider implementation that start with "Broken*":

- BrokenJCEBlockCipher.java
- BrokenKDF2BytesGenerator.java
- BrokenPBE.java

They have many more classes within the files but as far as I can tell, they are not being called by anything outside of other "Broken" clases. This begs the following questions:

- Why are they called that way?
- Why do they exist?

Comment: Could you ask on the developers mailing list of Bouncy Castle and report back? *Why* questions can normally only be answered by the original author, unless a very clear logical reason exists.

Comment: Did you download the tests and see if the broken algorithms are used from there? The broken classes cannot be in the test repo itself as they would not be included in the signed provider.